# Manage a queue of requests in C

Tags: multithreading, queue

I have a multithreaded program that processes images and I want to make a queue in the program for inserting requests from an external program in this queue and the image processor's threads dequeue the requests from it. Now what is the best solution for when the queue is full and new requests arrive?Should I drop new or old or random requests?

Answer (score 0):

That is totally up to you and how you want your program to behave. See what the outcome of each decision might lead and decide which is the lesser evil.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [message broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) for this approach.

You can send the images as messages to this broker which will handle the routing to the target program, the complete queuing system as well as the "full queue" problem.

I personally have made some good experience with [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), although it might be a little overhead for your special purpose. You may have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) as well as it might be a little thinner and a better approach for you.

To do things right, determine what you really need and check out if those message broker are really useful in your current situation - from my point of view and in my opinion they are, but depends on your exact requirements and implementation.

If you're interested look at [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol), the Advanced Messaging Queuing Protocol itself - it's the basic for all those message brokers and quite interesting.